# PHP cURL download does not work when called from browser

Tags: php, web-applications

I want a php script which I can access from browser and that script will download files to my remote server (not to my computer). 
This is complete code which I call from browser as localhost/download.php but it does not work (in network manager I see that something is being downloaded but in project folder I can not find it):

```
<?  
    function download($url, $referer, $name)
    {
        $path = $name.'.mp3';
        $fp = fopen($path, 'w');
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:13.5) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.4.9\r\n',
                    "Referer: $referer" 
        ));
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        fwrite($fp, $data);
        fclose($fp);
    }

    echo 'Please wait it is downloading...<br/>';
    /*$url = $_GET['url'];
    $referer = $_GET['referer'];
    $name = $_GET['name'];*/
    $url = "http://stream.get-tune.net/file/91259796/101538464/3652118538/ee58ddeb905ffa12/Palwan_Halmyradow_-_Sensiz_(get-tune.net).mp3";
    $referer = "http://get-tune.net/?a=music&q=palwan+halmyradow";
    $name = "Palwan Halmyradow - Sensiz";
    download($url, $referer, $name);
?>
```

But it works when I call below command from command line:

```
php /var/www/idym/download.php
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Where are you writing anything to the file?

Comment: @vaneto I want to download files to my server. And for memory reasons, I am directly writing it.

Comment: This here should work:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926944/downloadable-mp3-files-from-php-headers-not-working

;)

Comment: @inkytales dont think so

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

the difference might be a result of different config for cli php and apache php.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

complete code:

```
function download($url, $referer, $name)
{
    $path = $name.'.mp3';
    $fp = fopen($path, 'w');
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:13.5) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.4.9\r\n',
                "Referer: $referer" 
    ));
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: @torayeff if you set this option, contents of the response will be stored in $data in your code. you need to run file_put_contents('path/to/file', $data); or so to save it

Comment: :) Not lazy. But it really does not work. I edited my question with full code which I use.

Comment: if we are using curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); we do not need curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); so ;)

Comment: ok my bad. i missed that, please add var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch)); before curl_close. most probably apache user does not have perrmision to write file so also check if fopen does not return 0.

Comment: exactly. I just wanted to answer my own question :). The problem with file permissions. Browser can not write files in /var/www/.